# How to detect that a scroll bar knob is being dragged by the user

Tags: winapi, scrollbar

I have (old...) code that updates the scrollbar position and min-max values in the background with `SetScrollRange()` but this code should not run while the user is dragging the scrollbar knob as it makes the knob visually jump back to the original position and then jumps back to the user's selected position when he drags or releases the mouse.

Is there some easy way to detect that the dragging is going on?

Comment: [`SB_THUMBTRACK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787577(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @zett42 That will tell me it was dragged recently when treating that message, not when treating some other message (in this case a background timer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this. The easy (and hacky) way to do it is to call GetCapture(). It will return the HWND value of the current window that has captured the mouse, or NULL if the mouse is not captured. This simply means that the user has pushed the mouse button within the scrollbar control without releasing the mouse button.

The better way to do it would be to subclass the control. Here's some example code on how you could set a flag if the scrollbar's "thumb" is being dragged:

```
// Somewhere in your code, subclass the scrollbar
WNDPROC originalScrollBarWndProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(scrollBarHwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR) myScrollBarWndProc);

LRESULT CALLBACK myScrollBarWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            // Get Y position of the mouse
            uint16_t mouseYPos = HIWORD(lParam); // Change this to LOWORD for horizontal scrollbars

            // Get the top and bottom coordinates of the scrollbar thumb
            SCROLLBARINFO sbi = {0};
            sbi.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLBARINFO);

            if(GetScrollBarInfo(hwnd, OBJID_CLIENT, &sbi) == 0)
            {
                // Failed to get scroll bar info, handle however you want
                break;
            }

            // Check if the WM_LBUTTONDOWN event happened over the scrollbar thumb
            if(mouseYPos >= sbi.xyThumbTop && mouseYPos <= sbi.xyThumbBottom)
            {
                // Set a flag to indicate that the thumb is being "dragged"
                // I chose to do this using SetWindowLongPtr; Do it however you like.
                SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR) 1);
            }
        }
        break;

        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        {
            // Mouse button was released, clear the flag
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR) 0);
        }
        break;

        /* ... other cases here, if needed ... */
    }

    return CallWindowProc(originalScrollBarWndProc, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Using the code above, all you'd have to do is call GetWindowLongPtr(scrollBarHwnd, GWLP_USERDATA) and check if the value is 0 or 1 to see if it's being dragged or not.

I'm not positive this is the **best** approach to the problem, but I am sure it is at least a good one that will work well.

Answer (score 4):

When the user is dragging around the scrollbar's thumb, the scrollbar's owner window receives [`WM_VSCROLL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430018.aspx) (vertical) or [`WM_HSCROLL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430017.aspx) (horizontal) messages (depending on the orientation of the scrollbar), where the lo-word of the `wParam` value is set to `SB_THUMBTRACK` and the hi-word is set to the new position.

When the user releases the thumb, the owner window receives two final `WM_(V|H)SCROLL` messages:

- the first message has the lo-word of the `wParam` value set to `SB_THUMBPOSITION` and the hi-word set to the new position.
- the second message has the lo-word of the `wParam` set to `TB_ENDTRACK`.

You can subclass the UI control that owns the scrollbar to intercept those messages.  When you see any `WM_(V|H)SCROLL` messages, don't make updates to the scrollbar until you see a `TB_ENDTRACK` notification.

Comment: So I can set some global/static state when I get the 1st `SB_THUMBTRACK` and reset this when I see the `TB_ENDTRACK`?

Comment: @ErikElmgren yes